# Where did my points go?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, excel

I had an excel file marking points on my map. I then added a base map and my points are gone. Even with the base map layer turned off the points do not show. I tried reordering the layers and tried deleting then re-adding the excel file and nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Which software do you use? I assume you mean ArcGIS, since Excel alone is not able to provide a map.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. ArcGIS 10.1.

Comment: 99% a projection issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most definitely a projection issue. If the data frame is in a projected coordinate system and measured in meters, and the values in the excel file are in a geographic coordinate system and in something like decimal degrees, the points will almost disappear. This is because the excel values are being read as meters, when they are decimal degrees (lat 64.04, lon -139.4 = 64.04 meters, -139.4 meters). Try right clicking on the points and Zoom to Layer - you may be able to zoom in to almost 1:1 scale and see the points, or the points may not even appear. 
If the excel file is from a GPS, try right clicking on the Layers in the table of contents, Coordinate System, Geographic Coordinate Systems, World, WGS 1984 and importing the excel file.